# Spring-boot - Custom validation for two related fields

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

```
@Column(length = 100)
private String post;

@NotNull
@Column
private String name;
```

How can I achieve the validation that

- Must not accept name if post is empty or null

Any idea how can I start with this?

Comment: What do you mean by "not accept" name if post is empty or null?

Comment: The name cannot be accepted if the post is empty or null. It means throw an error if this happens

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create a class level constraint.

1. Create an annotation
2. Create a ConstraintValidator

Here is an example from the docs: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-class-level-constraints

package org.hibernate.validator.referenceguide.chapter06.classlevel;

The annotation:

```
@Target({ TYPE, ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = { ValidPassengerCountValidator.class })
@Documented
public @interface ValidPassengerCount {

    String message() default "{org.hibernate.validator.referenceguide.chapter06.classlevel." +
            "ValidPassengerCount.message}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default { };

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { };
}
```

The validator

```
package org.hibernate.validator.referenceguide.chapter06.classlevel;

public class ValidPassengerCountValidator
        implements ConstraintValidator<ValidPassengerCount, Car> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(ValidPassengerCount constraintAnnotation) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Car car, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if ( car == null ) {
            return true;
        }

        return car.getPassengers().size() <= car.getSeatCount();
    }
}
```

Then you can use the annotation on class level:

package org.hibernate.validator.referenceguide.chapter02.classlevel;

```
@ValidPassengerCount
public class Car {

    private int seatCount;

    private List<Person> passengers;

    //...
}
```

Comment: im getting @ValidPassengerCount not applicable to type

Comment: Ok isolve the not applicable type but theres no error message and the insert is still going through

Comment: Do you have spring-boot-starter-validation as dependency?

Answer (score 2):

For example, if we want to check whether a DTO object is valid, by comparing its two attributes `dueDate` and `repeatUntil` , following are the steps to achieve it. If you need a detailed explanation on steps, have a look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6pkaYjJVlyk).

dependency in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

DTO class:

```
@ValidTaskDTO
public class TaskDTO {

    @FutureOrPresent
    private ZonedDateTime dueDate;

    @NotBlank(message = "Title cannot be null or blank")
    private String title;

    private String description;

    @NotNull
    private RecurrenceType recurrenceType;

    @Future
    private ZonedDateTime repeatUntil;

}
```

Custom Annotation:

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = {TaskDTOValidator.class})
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ValidTaskDTO {
    String message() default "Due date should not be greater than or equal to Repeat Until Date.";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Constraint Validator:

```
public class TaskDTOValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidTaskDTO, TaskDTO> {
    @Override
    public void initialize(ValidTaskDTO constraintAnnotation) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(TaskDTO taskDTO, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        if (taskDTO.getRecurrenceType() == RecurrenceType.NONE) {
            return true;
        }

        return taskDTO.getRepeatUntil() != null && taskDTO.getDueDate().isBefore(taskDTO.getRepeatUntil());
    }
}
```

Make sure that you have `@Valid` in front of RequestBody of a postmapping method in your RestController. Only then the validation will get invoked:

```
@PostMapping
public TaskReadDTO createTask(@Valid @RequestBody TaskDTO taskDTO) {
.....
}
```